# sum of row values if greater than zero

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, sum, row

I want to sum all values for each row in a pandas dataframe if they are greater than zero

my dataframe looks like this:

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4
 5     4   -2     1
 3     6    2    -3
 2    -2    1     1
```

and I want to add a new column with the sum of the positive values. So it should look like this:

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4 sum
 5     4   -2     1   10
 3     6    2    -3   11
 2    -2    1     1    2
```

Comment: So don't you want to perform a conditional select ( >=0) and perform an aggregrate SUM() function on the results of that?

Comment: how would I state that? df[allrowvalues>0].sum(axis=1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
df.where(df > 0).sum(1)

Out[34]:
0    10.0
1    11.0
2     4.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative solution, we can make use of [**`.clip(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) to map all values below `0` to `0`, and then sum over the second axis:

```
>>> df.clip(lower=0).sum(axis=1)
0    10
1    11
2     4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as it allows chaining and needs no intermediary variable